# Can I use rings off a pull-up bar?

Tags: home-exercise, rings

I've seen people online espousing the benefits of rings for all sorts of exercise. I don't want to fix mounts onto my ceiling so I wondered whether I can hang them from a pull-up bar?

You'd have quite a short rope to each ring (4 feet?) and I don't know if that's OK. How far out from the wall does the pull-up bar need to be, and how best to attach the rings (ends or middle)?

Comment: Rings hanging from the pull-up bar are fine. You'll probably want to make the height adjustable for different exercises. Everything else is just an engineering question and dependent on what is available to you and what type of rings you have.

Answer (score 4):

**Can you hang rings from pull-up bars?**

- Absolutely. Typically if I see rings in home gyms, they are tied onto doorway pullup bars. Rings on a wall mounted pull-up bar would likely be even better as long as you can hang it high enough.

**Is length of rope an issue?**

- It is easy to find rings with adjustable straps, so you can adjust
  how long the strap is based on the exercise you are doing.

**How far away from the wall should the bar be?**

- It depends on what exercises you are looking to do. The farther away it is from the wall
  the more options you will have. This [wall mounted pull-up bar](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00HF8U37U) is
  32 inches away from the wall and should be plenty of room for the
  average sized human to do most exercises. For advanced calisthenics exercises, such as planches and levers it will have to extend half your height, plus a few inches. If you are that dedicated, it might be better to build a free standing bar.

**Where to attach the rings**

- I assume you are asking because you don't want the ring straps to slip. In my experience, they don't slip much if at all because most of the the force is being applied downward, not laterally. If you are looking to ensure they don't slip, shoulder width works great. You specifically ask if ends or middle are better. In that case it really depends on how long the straps are, and how wide your pull up bar is. The closest to shoulder width is going to be the best for most exercises. You don't want to be bumping into the straps, but it would be even worse to have the rings set much wider than shoulder width since it would be applying outward lateral pressure on your arms if you try to do dips or something similar.